# Keep element at height after animating

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to increase an elements height when hovering over it but at the moment when you move the mouse away from the element it reverts the height, is there a way to keep the element at the height I animate to? Here's my code so far:

```
var width = $(window).width();
$("#projects .project:first").addClass("active");
$("#projects .project:first").height(100);
if (width > 800) {
    $('#projects .project').hover(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var prev = $("#projects .project.active");
        $('#projects .project').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        if ($(this).find("p").text().trim().length) {
            $(this).animate({
                height: '100px'
            }, { duration: 1000, queue: false });
            $(prev).animate({
                height: '30px'
            }, { duration: 1000, queue: false });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: use `mouseover()` instead of hover https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found in the end the best solution to achieve the functionality I wanted was using accordion: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/